# JAXB exception handling

Tags: java, exception, jaxb

I have called `unmarshalling()` in `createPartControl()` method and `marshalling()` in `btnSave()` method, I want to know what exception it will throw? I have added try, catch block over there. I am not sure can we add throws or not. pls some one explain.

```
public void createPartControl(final Composite parent) {

    try {
        MarshallingUnmarshalling.unMarshaling();
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
    associateViewer = new TreeViewer(parent, SWT.FULL_SELECTION);

    associateViewer.addPostSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
            if (imageText.getText().equals("")) {
                final ImageLoader loaderNoImage = new ImageLoader();
                loaderNoImage.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("icons/no.png"));
                final Image noImage = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), loaderNoImage.data[0]);
                labelImage.setImage(noImage);

            } else {
                labelImage.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(imageText.getText()));

            }

        }
    });

    associateViewer.setSorter(new Sorter());
    tree = associateViewer.getTree();
    GridData gridTree = new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.FILL, false, false, 1, 1);
    gridTree.widthHint = 942;
    gridTree.heightHint = 171;
    tree.setLayoutData(gridTree);
    tree.setHeaderVisible(true);
    tree.setLinesVisible(true);

    final TreeColumn newColumnTableColumn = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.NONE);
    newColumnTableColumn.setWidth(342);
    newColumnTableColumn.setText("Name");
    final TreeColumn newColumnTableColumn1 = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.NONE);
    newColumnTableColumn1.setWidth(372);
    newColumnTableColumn1.setText("E-mail");
    final TreeColumn newColumnTableColumn2 = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.NONE);
    newColumnTableColumn2.setWidth(252);
    newColumnTableColumn2.setText("Phone");

    labelImage = new Label(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    GridData gLabelImage = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1);
    gLabelImage.heightHint = 695;
    labelImage.setLayoutData(gLabelImage);

    new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);

    Label lblImageLocation = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
    lblImageLocation.setText("Image Location");

    final Composite detailComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    GridData gDetailComposite = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.TOP, false, false, 1, 5);
    gDetailComposite.widthHint = 963;
    detailComposite.setLayoutData(gDetailComposite);
    final GridLayout gridLayout2 = new GridLayout();
    gridLayout2.numColumns = 2;
    detailComposite.setLayout(gridLayout2);

    final Label descriptionLabel = new Label(detailComposite, SWT.NONE);
    descriptionLabel.setText("Description:    ");
    new Label(detailComposite, SWT.NONE);

    final Label label = new Label(detailComposite, SWT.NONE);
    label.setText("Name:   ");

    nameText = new Text(detailComposite, SWT.BORDER);
    nameText.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));

    final Label emailLabel = new Label(detailComposite, SWT.NONE);
    emailLabel.setText("E-mail:");

    emailText = new Text(detailComposite, SWT.BORDER);
    emailText.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));

    final Label phoneLabel = new Label(detailComposite, SWT.NONE);
    phoneLabel.setText("Phone:");

    phoneText = new Text(detailComposite, SWT.BORDER);
    phoneText.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));

    imageText = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    GridData gImageText = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, false, false, 1, 1);
    gImageText.widthHint = 414;
    imageText.setLayoutData(gImageText);

    final Button btnBrowse = new Button(parent, SWT.NONE);

    btnBrowse.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

            FileDialog dlg = new FileDialog(parent.getShell(), SWT.OPEN);
            String fileName = dlg.open();
            if (fileName != null) {
                imageText.setText(fileName);
                labelImage.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(imageText.getText()));

            }
        }
    });

    btnBrowse.setText("Browse");

    GridData gBtnBrowse = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1);
    gBtnBrowse.heightHint = 51;
    gBtnBrowse.widthHint = 155;
    btnBrowse.setLayoutData(gBtnBrowse);

    final ImageLoader loaderBrowse = new ImageLoader();
    loaderBrowse.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("icons/brw.png"));
    final Image browseImage = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), loaderBrowse.data[0]);
    btnBrowse.setImage(browseImage);

    final Button btnSave = new Button(parent, SWT.NONE);
    btnSave.addMouseMoveListener(new MouseMoveListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseMove(MouseEvent e) {
            btnSave.setText("Save   ");
            final ImageLoader loaderSaveImage = new ImageLoader();
            loaderSaveImage.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("icons/clicktosave.png"));
            final Image saveImage = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), loaderSaveImage.data[0]);
            btnSave.setImage(saveImage);
        }
    });

    GridData gBtnSave = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1);
    gBtnSave.heightHint = 56;
    gBtnSave.widthHint = 156;
    btnSave.setLayoutData(gBtnSave);
    btnSave.setText("Save   ");

    final ImageLoader loaderSaveImage = new ImageLoader();
    loaderSaveImage.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("icons/clicktosave.png"));
    final Image saveImage = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), loaderSaveImage.data[0]);
    btnSave.setImage(saveImage);
    new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
    new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);

    btnSave.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            try {
                MarshallingUnmarshalling.marshaling();
            } catch (JAXBException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            final ImageLoader loaderSavedImage = new ImageLoader();
            loaderSavedImage.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("icons/saved.png"));
            final Image savedImage = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), loaderSavedImage.data[0]);
            btnSave.setText("Saved");
            btnSave.setImage(savedImage);
        }
    });

    associateViewer.setContentProvider(new TreeContentProvider());
    associateViewer.setLabelProvider(new TreeLabelProvider());
    associateViewer.setInput(Engineer);

    Binding.initDataBindings();
    }

    @Override
    public void setFocus() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course you can add try-catch blocks for marshaling\unmarshaling. But you also need to handle exceptions gracefully. Depending on the exception you may show appropriate error dialog, return some default value etc. There are many possible solutions. Do you need to throw it out of `widgetSelected`? No, and I'm pretty sure compiler won't let you.

Comment: I have to throw for marshalling() and unmarshalling(). I have one more question- We should  use Throws or Try,Catch ?  For mashalling and unmarshalling,what kind of exception it will throw?

Comment: AFAIK the exception is `JAXBException` regarding throws vs try-catch for your example I would use it like you did and show appropriate error dialog in catch block.

Comment: so,in the catch block I have to use System.out.println to display the error message in the console.

Comment: marshalling and unmarshalling would only throw JAXBexception or anything else?

Comment: I need to take a look at `MarshallingUnmarshalling` class to see all possible variants. But if you don't do anything unusual there `JAXBException` would be thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do:

```
@Override
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
    try {
        MarshallingUnmarshalling.marshaling();
        // or MarshallingUnmarshalling.unMarshaling();
     } catch (JAXBException e) {
         showError(e);
     }
}

private void showError(Exception e) {
    final Text text = new Text(composite, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    text.setText("An error occurred!");
    text.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
    Status status = new Status(IStatus.ERROR, "Plug-in ID", 0,
        "Status Error Message", e);

    ErrorDialog.openError(Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell(),
        "Error!", text.getText(), status);
}
```

So, basically you create handy method for error showing and then use it in both (marshalling and unmarshalling) catch block.

Comment: Thank you Enigo :) I will try this .

Comment: If one dont want to use JAXB, how do we store and transform data from some file?

Comment: This is rather broad question actually. It depends on the needs of the project. There are many many ways to do it) you may use csv, json or raw data, and each of them would have different approach.

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. [More info](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)